# Is this inductor ok?

Tags: inductor, damage, ozone

I was cleaning a 10+ year old LCD TV with a damp rag and noticed an ozone-like smell. I assumed a chip was frying or something was arcing. I unplugged it, gave the power supply some time to discharge, opened it up, then plugged it in and turned it on, hoping to see something obviously bad, but I didn't. This is on the logic board, not the power supply.

It could be any component nearby, but I didn't like the look of this inductor, especially the first picture. There wasn't much dust on the board, but the inductor looked a little melted or gunky.

Maybe it's been like this for a long time, but I thought I could smell it several feet away after I first noticed. The plastic still smells, but a lot of electronics emit low amounts of ozone, so maybe it's just been baking in it for a decade.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. The orange stuff is solder flux, a residue also seen on other components.

The smell *might* be confused with common electrical smells such as phenol or burnt epoxy, though they're quite different when compared directly.

If it is a burnt-epoxy smell, it could be as innocent as PCB laminate outgassing, or as dramatic as cratered components.

There probably isn't anything high voltage inside there, anyway; not that would yield more ozone than combustion, anyway.  That is -- give or take CCFL backlights, which might be here or there in ca. 2013 units, I'm not sure.  It would be a fairly unusual failure to get HV leakage there, though I don't know the chances of that as I don't repair TVs.